Mongodb Restore Failing with error - applyOps: (KeyNotFound) No keys found for HMAC that is valid for time
I am running mongodb restore using the mongorestore tool on database version 6.0.14 enterprise with mongodb tools version as 100.9.4
"2024-07-17T13:56:35.294+0500    Failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: (KeyNotFound) No keys found for HMAC that is valid for time: { ts: Timestamp(1721206595, 5) } with id: 0"

I tried to search the solution, posted in the mongodb community also however no one has replied, please help community users.
I tried to search about the issue at multiple sites including mongodb community however no solution was offered.
